# Understanding os bootloading - assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system

I am trying to go more indepth os understanding. So, the linux boot has to deal with an assembly file. I know about `mov, push, pop,` but here I am quite lost with this :

```
.globl  __start
    .ent    __start
__start:
    br  $29,2f
2:  ldgp    $29,0($29)
    jsr $26,start_kernel
    call_pal PAL_halt
    .end __start

switch_to_osf_pal:
    subq    $30,128,$30
...
```

Am I correct if I say that `__start` is a label ? So will it be called as soon as it is called in an other peace of code ? I tried to google around to understand the `ldgp`, or `call_pal` symbols but I found nothing. At last, I found in c files that `switch_to_osf_pal` is called in this way `switch_to_osf_pal(2, pcb_va, pcb_pa, VPTB);` is this functions taking this params call the assembly function ?

Sorry if there is a to much questions, but I didn't find any clear doc

Comment: is this the code for the Alpha architecture? If you want to explore the linux boot loader you might be able to find information much more readily if you explore a more common architecture

Comment: @msam I thinks it is indeed an Alpha architecture. What kind of architecture should I explore ?

Comment: x86 and arm come to mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__start` is a label.

`ldgp` means *load global pointer* in [Alpha assembly](http://www.alphalinux.org/wiki/index.php/Alpha_Assembly).

`call_pal`means *call privileged architecture library*. It is an unconditional jump to an exception handler.

More information in [Assembly Programmer's Guide](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f98/doc/alpha-asm.pdf)